# Why is my GitHub pages website displaying a blank page when deployed?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, github-pages, manifest.json, index.html

I am hosting a React app on  github pages. Currently, the page is blank and no data is displaying and I am getting these errors in the console. If I run the project locally, there are no issues, it is only the deployed version that is having issues:

```
/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json:1     
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

Here is my project structure:

```
├── CNAME
├── index.html  
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json  
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
│   ├── CNAME  
│   ├── favicon.ico  
│   ├── index.html  
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt  
├── src
│   ├── App.js  
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── C++.png
│   │   ├── StreetAssist.png
│   │   ├── WHDparser.PNG
│   │   ├── angular.png
│   │   ├── aws.png
│   │   ├── bereaCollege.jpg
│   │   ├── bootstrap.png
│   │   ├── css.png
│   │   ├── ecoB4C.jpg
│   │   ├── flask.png
│   │   ├── git.png
│   │   ├── github.png
│   │   ├── golang.png
│   │   ├── html.png
│   │   ├── javascript.png
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   ├── mold.png
│   │   ├── mysql.png
│   │   ├── powershell.png
│   │   ├── python.png
│   │   ├── react.png
│   │   ├── reactPortfolio.PNG
│   │   ├── sqlite.png
│   │   └── tailwind.png
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── About.jsx
│   │   ├── Contact.jsx
│   │   ├── Experience.jsx
│   │   ├── Home.jsx
│   │   ├── Navbar.jsx
│   │   ├── Skills.jsx
│   │   └── Work.jsx
│   ├── index.css
│   └── index.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

Hosted website: https://www.garrett-clark.com/

Repository: https://github.com/Boorclark/boorclark.github.io

Comment: Add `"homepage": "./"` to the `package.json`. Your page is not displaying because you assets paths are wrong

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I still got these errors in the console:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
manifest.json:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy a React.js application on GitHub Pages, follow these steps:

- **Install `gh-pages` Package:** Install this on your project's root directory

```
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

- **Configure `package.json`:** Add the following property

```
"homepage": "https://<username>.github.io/<repository-name>"
```

- **Modify Your `package.json` Scripts:** add or update the "scripts" section to include these two scripts

```
"scripts": {
  ...,
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

[image: Script File]
*Image Credit: https://blog.logrocket.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/commands.png*

- Now, Re-configure to deploy again on the GitHub pages. Hope it will work seamlessly with you. You can also check the blog on the internet.
  Recently I used this blog [Deploying React apps to GitHub Pages](https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/) for my project as a reference.

Comment: Let me know if you get any errors.